# Control hair particles with the curve in Blender 2.93

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair

I am trying to do basic hair control with the curve and I  am constantly getting this (image attached). It looks like there is a lack of segments, but no matter how much I increase them nothing changes. What could possibly cause this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The number of segments (50) under *Emission* is not what you see in the viewport. There are a few other settings that control this.

Two of them are in the *Particle Settings*

- first located in *Render > Path > Steps*: `5`. Increase this value for the render. It's a value of the power of 2 but the default value (3) can be too low. 5 is a good value.
- the other is *Viewport Display > Strand Steps: `5`. This is what you're looking for because the default value (2) is also a bit low.
- [image: strand step settings]

Last but not least there is one more of these values in the *Comb* mode

- it's in the section *Options > Path Steps*: `5` of the tool settings in the <kbd>N</kbd>-panel and in *Active Tool Settings*. The default value here is 2. You only need this when you edit the hair.